# How to display current time in logs using XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How to display current time/date in Logs using XSLT-2.0 .

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Date functions are available natively

```
<xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>
```

There is also current-date() and current-time().

Comment: Thanks For Replay. Used same <xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/> statement at different places[i.e different templates]. Getting output is same time . it's doesn't show time difference even in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a date-time that varies during the course of execution of a stylesheet, then you need to be aware that the order of execution is totally unpredictable, and therefore the actual timestamps will be rather meaningless. You can get surprises, for example doing

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select="java:timestamp()"/>
```

at the start and then

```
<xsl:variable name="end" select="java:timestamp()"/>
```

and then outputting $end - $start, and finding the result is negative, because variables are evaluated when they are first referenced.

So you can get a system timestamp by calling extension functions (the details depend on your processor), but you need to be careful what you are asking for.